# .htaccess and Session

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

A link comes from an external website on my website with the following line:
 https://mywebsite.com/transfer.html?id=34.

A PHP script puts the id in $ _SESSION: here 34.

My question: I wish, once the id (34) puts the id in $ _SESSION, that the display of the link be modified as follows - hide the variable id to display only the website:
https://mywebsite.com/

I tried this in .htaccess:
`RewriteRule ^/?transfer\.html https://mywebsite.com [L]`
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=[0-9]{1,2}$`
`RewriteRule /$ /? [R=301,L]`

But the concern is that I get:
https://mywebsite.com/?id=34

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What you have tried? Additionally, it does not need the `.htaccess` You just need [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirects.

Comment: If you redirect from `https://mywebsite.com/transfer.html?id=34` to `https://mywebsite.com/` on the .htaccess level, then where and when would PHP even have a chance to grab that ID value, to put it into the session? This makes little sense to begin with. Redirect from within the PHP script itself instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but I do not have sufficient knowledge.  @SaidbakR: I never did this with a header - can you tell me about it.

Comment: @CBroe: yes, for sure.  I have also noticed this and that is the reason for my request to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I followed SaidbakR's advice and do this directly in my function file - indeed, no need for the .htaccess:

```
header ('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);
header ('Location: /');
exit ();
```

And the redirection works wonderfully.

Thanks for the movement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to https://mywebsite.com/34 and make sure the RewriteRule picks up the 34 and makes it ?id=34. Just the other way arround :)